# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

This is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the error I get when I run `gradle build`

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I have multi module project, here is my `settings.gradle`

```
include 'module-1'
include 'module-2'
include 'module-3'
include 'module-4:java'
include 'module-5'

rootProject.name = 'my-root-project'
```

What I am trying to do is have sub module use plugin `com.android.application`; here is build.gradle for `plugin1` which is Android app project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// ...
```

Comment: `dependencies` does not go inside of `repositories`. That `dependencies` looks like it belongs inside of a `buildscript` closure (e.g., https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/blob/v0.7/T02-Project/ToDo/build.gradle#L3-16).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the `dependencies` block out of `repositories` block:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
```

Something like that:

```
buildscript {    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        //...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()     
    }
}
```